# Illustrator: which canvas size and settings for new logo document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

What canvas size and other settings should I do in Illustrator when creating the main master design of any logo?

Answer (score 1):

You can really go with the defaults as this does not really impact your artwork directly, unless you are also preparing a presentation of some sort, in which case a format might be relevant. Otherwise, start a new file, make it 'Legal' or 'A4' in size and make sure to select CMYK in the 'Color Mode' box. You can adjust all these at a later stage if needed, so don't over think it.